# Mockito RestTemplate Test fails - HttpEntity has both entity and headers

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to mock a Rest Client using Mockito which takes in the following:-

MainServiceClass.java

```
public String serviceCall(String s1){

    String data2 = "s1";

  try{
      headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      headers.set("headers1", "headers1");

      HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(data2, headers);
        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(someurl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);

      return someString; }
```

ServiceTest.java

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RestTemplateTests {

 @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private Someservice service;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


        @Mock
        RestTemplate restTemplate;

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = mock(ResponseEntity.class);



    @Test
    public void myCallToTemplate() throws Exception {
    @Test
    public Mytestforcallingservice() {
      Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                                    someurl,
                                    HttpMethod.POST,
                                    Mockito.<HttpEntity<String>> any(),
                                    Mockito.<Class<?>> 
                                any())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
                    String s2 = service.serviceCall(s1);
                    Assert.assertEquals(s2, "hey");
    }
```

Below is my Error:-

```
.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
        Invalid use of argument matchers!
        4 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
        -> at com.example.MyServiceClass.Mytestforcallingservice(ServiceTest.java:110)
        -> at com.example.ServiceTest.Mytestforcallingservice(ServiceTest.java:110)

        This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
            //incorrect:
            someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
        When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
        For example:
            //correct:
            someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

The Test fails at forming HttpEntity which has both data2 and headers.
How can I form that in the Mockito call ?

Also, how can I verify it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mockito is saying you can't use argument matchers (in your case Mockito.any()) with raw values (in your case "someurl" and HttpMethod.POST)
So either you remove your argument matchers or you add an argument matcher to your raw values. Mockito.eq on "someurl" and HttpMethod.POST in your case would trigger the mock in your test. see below.

Also if you want to verify your rest template was invoked in a particular way you can use Mockito.verify(). See below to verify the rest template was invoked with a particular url

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class MyService {
    private String someurl = "myurl";
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public String serviceCall(String s1) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("headers1", "headers1");

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(s1, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(someurl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }

}
```

and

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RestTemplateTests {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private String testUrl = "myurl";
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService serviceClass;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        String expectedBody = "hey";
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(expectedBody, HttpStatus.OK);
        when(restTemplate.exchange(eq(testUrl), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(), eq(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);
        String s2 = serviceClass.serviceCall("s1");
        verify(restTemplate, times(1)).exchange(eq(testUrl), any(), any(), eq(String.class));
        assertEquals(s2, expectedBody);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception clearly says that you can not mix mock values and raw values, in your case, you have passed two matcher, viz `Mockito.<HttpEntity<String>> any(), Mockito.<Class<?>> any()` and other raw values as it is, you should use `Matchers.eq` to pass your values to matcher like:

```
import org.mockito.Matchers.eq

Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                                eq(someurl),
                                eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                                Mockito.<HttpEntity<String>> any(),
                                Mockito.<Class<?>> any()))
       .thenReturn(responseEntity);
```